# Responsive website works in remote in chrome but not when it's live

Tags: css, responsive-design

When I'm "live" in chrome on 127.0.0.1 the website gallery is responsive to all sizes. When I upload it to the actual domain & host the gallery is huge on all phones. Below is my code and CSS.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  #gallery {
      display: flex;
      margin: 10px auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      padding-top: $max-img-height/$max-img-width * 100%;
    }
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="gallery__item">
    <input type="radio" id="img-1" checked name="gallery" class="selector">
    <img class="gallery__img" src="images/p1.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery__item">
    <input type="radio" id="img-2" name="gallery" class="selector"/>
    <img class="gallery__img" src="images/p2.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add meta for viewports in head section?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />`

Comment: I do have     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing everything in context, but possibly your host is not getting compiled css....does `padding-top: $max-img-height/$max-img-width * 100%;` render as a value when you inspect in the browser?